# How do I set my default timezone to Ireland/dublin in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert to my timezone to ireland/Dublin ,currently its taking my system time. I have a different timezone.

Like 12:37 PM local time  to 7:00 AM (Ireland time)

I know in php it is very easy by using [date_default_timezone_set('Ireland/Dublin');](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Is it possible via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can get the local time with `Date`.
Then convert it to UTC time by adding the timezone offset to local time.
you can get the utc as follows:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

utc = localTime + offset ;
```

then add the Ireland offset i.e. +1 hour in milliseconds to the utc time.

you can refer: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329